# Finding Python recursive references

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I'm trying to find the recursive references in a given set of grammar expressions.
The following is an example:

```
expr   :  term
term   :  factor
factor :  expr
```

I don't know how to go about resolving the loops though.
I've tried to identify all recursive loops in a given dictionary which describes the rule references in the grammar.

Given the following tree, every node should be identified as recursive, as there is a loop from `expr -> term -> factor -> expr...`

```py
data = {
    'expr': {'term'},
    'term': {'factor'},
    'factor': {'expr'},
}
```

(it should also return all nodes that loop when there are multiple interconnected loops)

I'm not sure how to resolve which nodes are looping, I've looked around online and found this: https://github.com/we-like-parsers/pegen_experiments/blob/master/pegen/sccutils.py
but I couldn't understand how it solves a similar problem.

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat the grammar as a graph and check for cycles:

```
import re
s = """
expr   :  term
term   :  factor
factor :  expr
"""
g = [re.split('\s+:\s+', i) for i in filter(None, s.split('\n'))]
def check_cycle(n, c = []):
   if n in c:
      return True
   return any(check_cycle(b, c+[n]) for a, b in g if a == n)

result = {a:check_cycle(a) for a, _ in g}
```

Output:

```
{'expr': True, 'term': True, 'factor': True}
```